How to use Params to set weight of optional property
I want to use FactoryBoy to create some fake data with an optional property. I want to be able to override the probability that the property is None.

import random
from dataclasses import dataclass

import factory


@dataclass
class Data:
    address: str | None


def optional(decider: str, declaration):
    return factory.Maybe(
        factory.LazyAttribute(
            lambda o: random.random() <= getattr(o, decider)
        ),
        declaration,
        None,
    )


class DataFactory(factory.Factory):
    class Meta:
        model = Data

    class Params:
        has_address_probability = 0.5

    address = optional(
        "has_address_probability",
        factory.Faker("address"),
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = DataFactory(
        # Optionally override the probability
        has_address_probability=0
    )
    print(data)

